# VS2013 C++: Ignore Platform Include Folder

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, directx

I have a problem when moving to our company's build system over which I have limited control. They have installed DirectX SDK plus Windows 8.1 SDK... My applications is using 8.1 specific features that conflict with DirectX SDK (it's deprecated for a reason). So basically, they have the DirectX SDK hardwired into include lookup and thus headers will resolve to it instead of Windows SDK.

Is there a way to exclude specific folders from "#include" lookup no matter if they were specified? Or is there a way to remove the DirectX SDK from the built-in lookup by some MSBuild command line argument etc?

Hypothetical Solution:

IgnoreIncludeDirectories="C:/program files/directx SDK/include"

:)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming options (a) get your company to see the error in their ways, (b) remove the #include path from the VS settings and then manually specify them or (c) use a #IFDEF preprocessor to exclude the includes are not possible? I wonder whether conditional exclusion of the files of folders using this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171455(v=vs.100).aspx) might work for you?

Comment: AFAIK you can't exclude specific, but you can exclude all default: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93t31bx4.aspx

Comment: use windows xp toolset mode

Comment: Doesn't work... And windows XP mode is not possible as I need Windows 8.1 features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was easy.

```
set DXSDK_DIR=
%run your build script%
```

I am not sure if that is a general solution, but it worked and was suggested by one of our build engineers :). Maybe it will help someone else too.